# How to get a list of filter criteria from View to Controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ok, so I have a database of objects called Contacts:

```
public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        Interests = new List<Interest>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Interest> Interests { get; set; }

    public string AllInterests
    {
        get
        {
            string allInterests = "";
            foreach (Interest i in this.Interests)
            {
                allInterests += "[" + i.Name.ToString() + "] ";
            }

            return allInterests;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, as you can see, each contain a list of Interest objects:

```
public class Interest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

This is important, because I intend to include the ability to filter which Contacts from the database get sent to the Index view to be displayed in a table by whether or not their individual Interests contain one or more of the Interests chosen from the full list of Interests (or just show all of them if no Interests were selected. I cannot yet get this to work, but I imagine the code would look a little something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<InterestViewModel> filterList)
{
    List<Contact> allContacts = db.Contacts.ToList();
    List<Contact> filteredContacts = new List<Contact>();
    foreach(var filter in filterList.Where(f => f.IsSelected))
    {
        foreach(var contact in allContacts.Where(c => c.Interests.Any(i => i.Id == filter.Id)))
        {
            if (!filteredContacts.Contains(contact))
                filteredContacts.Add(contact);
        }
    }
    return View(filteredContacts);   
    //return View(db.Contacts.ToList());
}
```

There are probably a few reasons why this code isn't working, but first and foremost is the fact that I cannot for the life of me figure out how to actually return a list of Interests from a contact view, let alone get a working UI element to populate such a list from within the Index view itself. Could anyone here perhaps give some pointers for how to make something like this possible?

P.S. If it helps, I already know how to *create* a Contact with a user-populated list of Interests using these ViewModels:

```
public class ContactViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ChosenInterests> Interests { get; set; }
}



public class ChosenInterests
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

And this Partial View for creating a UI element that lets you select a subset of Interests from the full list:

```
@model ContactExperiment.ViewModels.ChosenInterests
@using ContactExperiment.ViewModels

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

(Which so far I have only gotten to work in the Create view here:)

```
@model ContactExperiment.ViewModels.ContactViewModel
@using ContactExperiment.ViewModels;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Contact</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "An email address is required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Interests, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Interests, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.Interests, "Must select at least one Interest", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

But I have yet to successfully re-purpose these for anything other than the creation of a new Contact and the population of its list of Interests.

EDIT: I suppose I should have included the code for the Index View itself, too. So far it just shows a list of all the Contacts and their relevant details just fine, but nothing else related to the filtering actions works or has been implemented:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactExperiment.Models.Contact>
@using ContactExperiment.ViewModels;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<div class="pull-right">
    @*@Html.EditorFor((ViewBag.InterestFilter as ICollection<ChosenInterests>).)*@
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Interests)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ListBox("Id", new SelectList(item.Interests, "Id", "Name"))*@
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AllInterests)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan, welcome to SO. Please post the code for the `Index` view.

Comment: @JuanR Done. I didn't really add it at first because it was still pretty bare-bones and didn't think it would be important, but I suppose if it's the part I'm asking for help on I should have shown it anyway.

Comment: I hear you. I only ask because sometimes the issue lies where you least expect it. Best to have everything available for inspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to find contacts that match the filters could be simplified to this:

```
public ActionResult Index(List<InterestViewModel> filterList)
{              
    //Generate a list of filtered ids
    var filterIds = filterList.Where(f => f.IsSelected).Select(f => f.Id);

    //Find contacts
    var filteredContacts = db.Contacts
    .Where(c => c.Interests.Any(i => filterIds.Contains(i.Id)))
    .Include(c => c.Interests)
    .ToList();

    //Make filters available to the view
    ViewBag.Filters = db.Interests.ToList();

    return View(filteredContacts);   
}
```

That should get you only the contacts that match any item in the filters. Note a few things. Selecting all contacts and materializing them to a list is expensive (the list could be large), so the select is made against the context itself. The result needs to include the navigational property `Interests`.

The view can use the dynamic property `ViewBag.Filters` to generate a list that the user can select from. You may be able to reuse your partial view to display it. Just make sure to work on the binding. You will also need to decide if you wish to have two separate actions, one for the initial load (`HttpGet`) and one for the subsequent calls (`HttpPost`, upon filtering).

Comment: This certainly helps, but there still remains the issue of creating/populating the list of Interests within the Contact Index view itself- as it stands filterList is currently a placeholder.

Comment: @NathanGonzalez I see. Can the filters be generated from a list somewhere or are you looking to generate them from the existing contacts?

Comment: The filters must be generated/populated from the full list of Interests, and presented in the view as a series of checkboxes indicating whether or not the user has chosen to filter the list of Contacts by if their Interests include the ones selected.

Comment: I can't get the Index view to recognize the contents of ViewBag.Filters as anything compatible with @Html.EditorFor() or otherwise access them.

Comment: @NathanGonzalez: You need to cast it. The `EditorFor` model looks at the model declared for the page. Since you are using the `ViewBag`, you cannot use this method. Instead, look to render it like you did in the Create view.

Comment: @NathanGonzalez. OK, it looks like you are going to need a model for the filtering. Create a view model class that has a property that will hold the filter selections, just like you do on your create model.

Comment: Done. Now what?

Comment: OH WAIT I GET IT NOW! Ok yeah that totally works, only minor annoyance is that the long vertically-aligned list of Interests isn't the prettiest of things, but it'll do for now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @NathanGonzalez: I am glad I was able to help. Good luck!